# Dismissing AlertDialog in Flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter, flutter-layout

I have simple Flutter app with list of items that are loaded from Firebase database (Cloud Firestore).

[image]

As you can see - there is button for adding items and each item can be deleted or edited. When I press edit button for selected item, AlertDialog with TextField appears, in this TextField user can see current item name and edit it.  **I have problems only with dismissing dialog after editing.**

```
   new IconButton(
      icon: new Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.white),
      onPressed: (){ showItemUpdateDialog(context, document); }
   )
   .......


void showItemUpdateDialog(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot item) {

  String itemName = "";
  var textContoller = new TextEditingController();
  textContoller.text = item['name'];

  var dialog = new AlertDialog(
    title: new Text("item name"),
    content: new TextField(
      controller: textContoller,
      onChanged: (value) {newName = value;},
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      new FlatButton(
        child: Text("cancel"),
        onPressed: (){
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
      new FlatButton(
          child: Text("Update"),
          onPressed: () { 
            updateItemOnServer(item, newName); 
            Navigator.pop(context); 
          }
      )
    ],
  );

  showDialog(context: context, child: dialog);
}
```

Value is updating correctly but AlertDialog is not dismissed. Error code is below. I think that it is due to that is was called by item that was modified and updated from server.

> flutter: The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
>   flutter: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
>   flutter: At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no
>   longer stable. To safely refer to a flutter: widget's ancestor in its
>   dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling flutter:
>   inheritFromWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies()
>   method.

Comment: Did you resolve this? If so, how?

Comment: Hello @moonvader Can you Please Help Me Out i want to implement same functionalities like you here is My question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092208/edit-listview-item-in-flutter-on-edit-click-using-dialog

Answer (score 13):

Try this,

```
 Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(),
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I had multiple navigators in my app and I couldn't figure out why none of the other answers would work for me.

Comment: @shanmugavel-gk can you please explain why does this work?

Comment: From the docs: If `rootNavigator` is set to true, the state from the furthest instance of this class is given instead. Useful for pushing contents above all subsequent instances of Navigator.

Answer (score 6):

With the **latest Flutter** use:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

instead of

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

For some reason it pops twice from the stack when popping **Dialog**

Do let me know if this solves the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/login'));
```