# Edit Listview Item on Edit Click Using Dialog

Tags: listview, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to edit an item On Edit Button Click. When a user presses on the edit button, I want a dialog with a `TextField` in it to appear so that the user can enter text in it and replace it with the text entered. I tried but I can't find any solutions. Please help me out with this. I attached a screenshot of my layout as well as posted some code.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp(
    items: List<String>.generate(100, (i) => "List item $i"),
  ));
}

Future<String> _asyncInputDialog(BuildContext context) async {
  String sampleText = '';
  return showDialog<String>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible:
    false, // dialog is dismissible with a tap on the barrier
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Enter Text'),
        content: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
                child: new TextField(
                  autofocus: true,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Text Here', hintText: 'eg. ABCD'),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    sampleText = value;
                  },
                ))
          ],
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Ok'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(sampleText);
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> items;

  MyApp({Key key, @required this.items}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Long List';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: widget.items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('${widget.items[index]}'),
              trailing: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Edit'),
                color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                onPressed: () async {
                  final String newText = await _asyncInputDialog(context);
                  setState(() {

                  });
                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text("$newText"),));
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Store the listview items in local storage using the sqflite package. You can edit them by editing the item in local storage directly and calling setState() to update the stateful widget. Here is a great tutorial showing you how: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BwjNEKD8g8&list=PLlxmoA0rQ-Lw6tAs2fGFuXGP13-dWdKsB&index=25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ListTile` put `items[index] = newText;` in `setState((){});` so I would look like this.

```
ListTile(
              title: Text('${items[index]}'),
              trailing: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Edit'),
                color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                onPressed: () async {
                  final String newText = await _asyncInputDialog(context);
                  setState(() {
                    items[index] = newText;
                  });
                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                    content: new Text("$newText"),
                  ));
                },
              ),
            );
```